# How can I custom table responsive materialize?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, responsive, materialize

My script like this :

```
<table class="responsive-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Mon</th>
        <th>Tue</th>
        <th>Wed</th>
        <th>Thr</th>
        <th>Fri</th>
        <th>Sat</th>
        <th>Sun</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
          <ul>
              <li>09:00-09:30</li>
              <li>10:00-10:30</li>
          </ul>
      </td>
      <td>
          <ul>
              <li>14:00-14:30</li>
          </ul>
      </td>
      <td>
          <ul>
              <li>12:30-13:00</li>
              <li>14:00-14:30</li>
          </ul>
      </td>
      <td>
          <ul>
              <li>15:00-16:00</li>
          </ul>
      </td>
      <td>
          <ul>
              <li>16:00-16:30</li>
          </ul>
      </td>
      <td>
          <ul>
              <li>09:00-09:30</li>
          </ul>
      </td>
      <td>
          <ul>
              <li>-</li>
          </ul>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/g9b7oj8t/

If it's accessed by desktop, it looks good

But if it's accessed by mobile, it looks messy

How do I customize css from materialize so that the display on mobile is neat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue with `Materialize`. [Here you find the reference to the problem.](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/4875)

This is the proposed solution on GitHub.

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Mon<br/>&nbsp;</th>
        <th>Tue<br/>&nbsp;</th>
        <th>Wed<br/>&nbsp;</th>
        <th>Thr<br/>&nbsp;</th>
        <th>Fri<br/>&nbsp;</th>
        <th>Sat<br/>&nbsp;</th>
        <th>Sun<br/>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

[Here the working example on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/StepBaro/0k4udqsr/1/)

But to works properly you can't use too many styles inside the cells, otherwise the heights won't be respected.

Comment: i actually need to use the ul tag inside td. because there are several considerations. but I will try to use your way. I thought about taking height from td and setting it to height from th. the way it works, only height doesn't work in safari browser

Comment: @SuccessMan [This is a quick test I did, I hope it helps you. JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/StepBaro/0k4udqsr/17/)

Answer (score 0):

You just have missed an outer `div`.
As per the BS4 guidelines -

> **To create a responsive table, enclose the table in a  element that has the .table-responsive class** (or one of the .table-responsive-* classes) applied.

So, your code ***with updated classes*** would be -

```html
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Mon</th>
        <th>Tue</th>
        <th>Wed</th>
        <th>Thr</th>
        <th>Fri</th>
        <th>Sat</th>
        <th>Sun</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <ul>
            <li>09:00-13:00</li>
            <li>10:00-14:30</li>
          </ul>
        </td>
        <td>
          <ul>
            <li>10:00-14:30</li>
          </ul>
        </td>
        <td>
          <ul>
            <li>09:00-13:00</li>
            <li>10:00-14:30</li>
          </ul>
        </td>
        <td>
          <ul>
            <li>09:00-13:00</li>
          </ul>
        </td>
        <td>
          <ul>
            <li>09:00-13:00</li>
          </ul>
        </td>
        <td>
          <ul>
            <li>09:00-13:00</li>
          </ul>
        </td>
        <td>
          <ul>
            <li>-</li>
          </ul>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<style>
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 5px;
}
</style>
```

**Refer [this](https://www.quackit.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_4/tutorial/bootstrap_tables.cfm) for more information**

Comment: I using materialize https://materializecss.com/table.html. So i  want the day names automatically move to the side